# In Spring vault is it possible to get events when the database credentials are rotataed with static role type through hashicorp vault

Tags: spring, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I'm using Spring vault to fetch the database credentials from hashicorp vault. Using SecretLeaseContainer and LeaseListener i'm able to get the events when the credentials are rotated for Dynamic secrets. Following is my code to get the events for dynamic credentials

```
SecretLeaseContainer container = new SecretLeaseContainer(getVaultTemplate());        
container.requestRotatingSecret("database/creds/dynamicRole");
container.addLeaseListener(vaultListener);
container.afterPropertiesSet();
container.start();
    
@Override
public void onLeaseEvent(SecretLeaseEvent secretLeaseEvent)
{
    if (secretLeaseEvent instanceof SecretLeaseCreatedEvent) {
       System.out.println("Secrets created: " + ((SecretLeaseCreatedEvent) secretLeaseEvent).getSecrets());
    }

    if (secretLeaseEvent instanceof SecretLeaseRotatedEvent) {
       System.out.println("Secrets rotated: " + ((SecretLeaseRotatedEvent) secretLeaseEvent).getSecrets());
    }
}
```

In the same way i tried to get the events when database credeantials are roatated with static role type, but its not working. Is it possible to get events when the database credentials are rotated with static role type? What should i need to do to get events?

Comment: What is your use case? Are you worried that the password changed since you last got it? Instead of watching events (that you could miss while restarting you app), just read the current password just-in-time, when you need it, for example to refresh your connection pool.